# I Have a Problem to Create a TopLevel in Python 3.11 in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, toplevel

I'm learning for my Tkinter Exam Tomorrow and I don't know why but when I'm trying to create a `TopLevel` in a new function, I'm getting this Error Message

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\kanne\OneDrive - csbme.de\Schuljahr2\Software\test.py", line 34, in login   
    pw_change()
  File "c:\Users\kanne\OneDrive - csbme.de\Schuljahr2\Software\test.py", line 7, in pw_change
    window2 = tk.Toplevel(window)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2653, in __init__
    self.title(root.title())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"
```

This is my Code I hope you can help me :)

```
import tkinter as tk

password_login = "123"
email_login = "asd"
def pw_change():

    window2 = tk.Toplevel(window)
    window2.title("Change")
    frame = tk.Frame(window2)
    pwchange_label = tk.Label(frame,text="Neues Passwort")
    pwchange_entry = tk.Entry(frame)

    pwagain_label = tk.Label(frame,text="Erneut eingeben")
    pwagain_entry = tk.Entry(frame)

    button = tk.Button(window2,text="Änder Passwort")

    pwchange_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
    pwchange_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
    pwagain_label.grid(row=1,column=0)
    pwagain_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)

    frame.pack()
    button.pack()
    window2.mainloop()


def login():
    print(farbe)
    if password_login == passwort_entry.get() and email_login == login_entry.get():
        text.config(text="Login erfolgreich", fg="green")
        print(var.get())
        if var.get() == True:
            pw_change()

    else:

        if farbe.get() == "blue":
                
            text.config(text="Login fehlgeschlagen", fg="blue")
        elif farbe.get() == "green":
            text.config(text="Login fehlgeschlagen", fg="green")


window = tk.Tk()
window.title = "Klausur"
farbe = tk.StringVar()
var = tk.BooleanVar()
image = tk.Label(window)
bild = tk.PhotoImage(file="1.png")
image["image"] = bild
frame = tk.Frame(window)
login_text = tk.Label(frame, text="E-Mail")
login_entry = tk.Entry(frame)
farbe.set("green")
radio_b = tk.Radiobutton(window, text="Blau", variable=farbe, value="blue")
radio_b2 = tk.Radiobutton(window,text="Grün", variable=farbe,value="green")


login_text.grid(row=0, column = 0,padx=5,pady=5)
login_entry.grid(row=0, column = 1,padx=5,pady=5)

passwort_text = tk.Label(frame, text="Passwort")
passwort_entry = t

k.Entry(frame,show="*")

passwort_text.grid(row=1, column = 0,padx=5,pady=5)
passwort_entry.grid(row=1, column = 1,padx=5,pady=5)
text = tk.Label(window)
button = tk.Button(window,text="Login",command = login)

pw_change1 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text="Passwort ändern",variable=var)
image.pack()
frame.pack()
radio_b.pack()
radio_b2.pack()
pw_change1.pack()
button.pack()
text.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I tried to Update the Python Version from 3.10 to 3.11.2 because I had some issues with self. Also I tried to import tkinter in a other way `from tkinter import *` and removed the `tk.` everywhere

Comment: Why do you duplicate  frame.pack()
    button.pack(). You already this. You should renamed it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As @toyotasupra mentioned, you also have a second instance of `mainloop()` which you don't need, as well as the `pack`/`grid` conflicts. Good catch!

There's a problem with how you're setting the `title` of the main window. You wrote:

```
window.title = "Klausur"
```

What you should use is:

```
window.title("Klausur")
```

As an aside, you should avoid using [star imports](https://code-maven.com/python-avoid-importing-everything) such as `from tkinter import *` as this can lead to so-called "namespace pollution". You're better off using `import tkinter as tk` and then prefixing tkinter objects with `tk.`

Answer (score 1):

- In line 16 `tk.Button(window2` to `tk.Button(frame1`
- In line 23-24 renamed to `frame1` and `button1`
- From line 74 to 79 change `.pack()` to `.grid()`
- Commented out line 25 `#window2.mainloop()`

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

password_login = "123"
email_login = "asd"
def pw_change():

    window2 = tk.Toplevel(window)
    window2.title("Change")
    frame1 = tk.Frame(window2)
    pwchange_label = tk.Label(frame1,text="Neues Passwort")
    pwchange_entry = tk.Entry(frame1)

    pwagain_label = tk.Label(frame1,text="Erneut eingeben")
    pwagain_entry = tk.Entry(frame1)

    button1 = tk.Button(frame1,text="Änder Passwort")

    pwchange_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
    pwchange_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
    pwagain_label.grid(row=1,column=0)
    pwagain_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)

    frame1.pack()
    button1.pack()
    #window2.mainloop()


def login():
    print(farbe)
    if password_login == passwort_entry.get() and email_login == login_entry.get():
        text.config(text="Login erfolgreich", fg="green")
        print(var.get())
        if var.get() == True:
            pw_change()

    else:

        if farbe.get() == "blue":
                
            text.config(text="Login fehlgeschlagen", fg="blue")
        elif farbe.get() == "green":
            text.config(text="Login fehlgeschlagen", fg="green")


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Klausur")
farbe = tk.StringVar()
var = tk.BooleanVar()
image = tk.Label(window)
bild = tk.PhotoImage(file="p1.png")
image["image"] = bild
frame = tk.Frame(window)
login_text = tk.Label(frame, text="E-Mail")
login_entry = tk.Entry(frame)
farbe.set("green")
radio_b = tk.Radiobutton(window, text="Blau", variable=farbe, value="blue")
radio_b2 = tk.Radiobutton(window,text="Grün", variable=farbe,value="green")


login_text.grid(row=0, column = 0,padx=5,pady=5)
login_entry.grid(row=0, column = 1,padx=5,pady=5)

passwort_text = tk.Label(frame, text="Passwort")
passwort_entry = tk.Entry()

tk.Entry(frame,show="*")

passwort_text.grid(row=1, column = 0,padx=5,pady=5)
passwort_entry.grid(row=1, column = 1,padx=5,pady=5)
text = tk.Label(window)
button = tk.Button(window,text="Login",command = login)

pw_change1 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text="Passwort ändern",variable=var)
image.grid()
frame.grid()
radio_b.grid()
radio_b2.grid()
pw_change1.grid()
button.grid()
text.grid()

window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]