# TypeError: 'Toplevel' object is not callable

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror, toplevel

I made a function in python

```
import tkinter as tk
import re
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import theFile.fileCentral as fc
import theData.workers as workerData
import theData.contracts as contractData

def openWorkers():
    workerData.workerWindow(root, tk, scrHeight, scrWidth)
```

The workerWindow function opens another window using the tkinter module, which I can close. But when I try to open it again, I get the error described in the title

```
contractData.contractWindow(root, tk, scrHeight, scrWidth)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'Toplevel' object is not callable
```

I asked Google, and as I understand, it is about how I handle and use the variables. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75593404/i-have-a-problem-to-create-a-toplevel-in-python-3-11-in-tkinter)

The function *contractWindow* is in its own file like this

```
openContractFlag = False



def contractWindow(contractRoot, contractTk, contractHeight, contractWidth):
    global openContractFlag                         
    contractWidth = int((contractWidth/2) - 600)                 
    contractHeight = int((contractHeight/2) - 500)               
    if openContractFlag == False:                   
        openContractFlag = True                     
        openContractWindow(contractRoot, contractTk, contractWidth, contractHeight) 



def openContractWindow(contractRoot, contractTk, contractWidth, contractHeight):
    global contractWindow        
    contractWindow = contractTk.Toplevel(contractRoot)                                                                                                                    
    contractWindow.title("Overenskomster")                                                                                                                
    contractWindow.geometry(f"900x800+{contractWidth}+{contractHeight}")                                                                                                  

    # Create new buttons in the new window                                                                                                                
    contractCloseButton = contractTk.Button(contractWindow, text="Luk", command=contractClose, bg="blue", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 16, "bold"))                     
    contractCloseButton.place(x=100, y= 10)                                                                                                                       

    newContract = contractTk.Button(contractWindow, text="Opret ny overenskomst", command=makeNewContract, bg="blue", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 16, "bold")) 
    newContract.place(x=200, y= 10)                                                                                                                       

    label = contractTk.Label(contractWindow, text="En liste med alle overenskomster", borderwidth=2, bg="black", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 16, "bold"))      
    label.place(x=270, y=70)                                                                                                                              


def contractClose():
    global openContractFlag
    if contractWindow is not None:
        openContractFlag = False
        contractWindow.destroy()

def makeNewContract():
    print("Make new contract")
```

I renamed the variables in this file/code block, to make sure they are not used elsewhere, but no success.

Comment: You use `contractWindow` as global variable in `openContractWindow`. You can't use it as name of a variable and a function at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code.

```
openContractFlag = False

def contractWindow(contractRoot, contractTk, contractHeight, contractWidth):
    global openContractFlag
    contractWidth = int((contractWidth/2) - 600)
    contractHeight = int((contractHeight/2) - 500)
    if openContractFlag == False:
        openContractFlag = True
        openContractWindow(contractRoot, contractTk, contractWidth, contractHeight)

def openContractWindow(contractRoot, contractTk, contractWidth, contractHeight):
    global openContractFlag  # Rename this variable if needed
    global contractWindowFlag  # Rename the global variable
    contractWindowFlag = contractTk.Toplevel(contractRoot)
    contractWindowFlag.title("Overenskomster")
    contractWindowFlag.geometry(f"900x800+{contractWidth}+{contractHeight}")

    # ... rest of the code ...

def contractClose():
    global openContractFlag
    global contractWindowFlag  # Update the variable name here
    if contractWindowFlag is not None:
        openContractFlag = False
        contractWindowFlag.destroy()

def makeNewContract():
    print("Make new contract")
```

Comment: This answer would be a lot more useful if you explained what you changed. Otherwise we have to compare the code line-by-line and character-by-character to the original.